# Call Docker-Compose commands in Go

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I want to make a CLI that provides some QoL Features for Docker-Compose in go, but unfortunately, I can't find any docs related to the API. I searched through the repo, but the codebase is quite nested and I can't get to the bottom of it. My only choice atm seems to just execute the commands using the shell..

My current best guess is to directly invoke [`(*github.com/docker/compose/pkg/api.ServiceProxy).RunOneOffContainer`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/run.go#L233) but I can't seem to figure out how to get all the dependencies like the cli and context.

TL;DR: how do I programmatically call docker-compose commands like `up`

Comment: afaik there is no compose sdk. I have asked this in the slack channel some time back.

Comment: Well thats... sad, can I maybe do something with the compose spec (github.com/compose-spec/compose-go)?

Comment: I dont think its easy because its wrapped in a command line app. The linked repo is for working with compose files. Like parsing them and so on.

Comment: My idea was to maybe be able to use the compose-spec repo to parse the compose files into something that the Docker SDK can use

Comment: ...which is broadly what `docker-compose` does already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no docker compose API. If you choice execute the docker-compose commands using the shell, then use 'exec.Command' in Go:

```
out, err := exec.Command("docker", "compose", "up").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```